# Can't read property push of undefined

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, mongoose, service

```js
userInfoList: any = [];
userInfoList: any[] = [];  // tried this also
this.userInfoList.push(payload);
```

I have tried a lot, but I am not getting the exact solution of this error.

Comment: The error message suggests that `userInfoList` is undefined, i.e. there is no array object there.  How does one normally declare an array in node.js that allows a `push` to occur?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have some class with `add` method.

There are two options you can achieve it:

**First option**

```js
class Foo {

  userInfoList: any[] = [];

  add(payload: number) {
    this.userInfoList.push(payload);
  }
}
```

**Second option**

```js
class Bar {

  constructor(public userInfoList: any[]) { }

  add(payload: number) {
    this.userInfoList.push(payload);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, but i have already done with first option and again getting same error of undefined and also tried with 2nd option but could not be able to achieve it. I am unable to find out the error behind this logic although everything is pretty clear

Comment: Please share your full code.
It is very hard to figure out your problem with only 3 lines of code

Comment: I got my error. basically it was from backend issue. Now my code is working correctly. thankyou so much @captain-yossarian for your precious time.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare it as const userInfoList = []; Then userInfoList.push()

Comment: You could try to declare it with 'var' instead. What does the payload contain?

Comment: payload actually contains data that i want to send at backend and after getting response from server i want to push in userInfoList.